# JavaScript to make spacing of sections on 'one-page' site hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on one of those 'trendy' one page sites where by when you click a menu option it scrolls you down to the area of the page.

I'm having this issue with regards to 'spacing' where for example if I click About Us on my menu, it scrolls down but shows part of the area below. (see screenshot):

[image: screenshot]

Take a look at my source if you wish: http://www.londonadvertising.com/2011/

Many Thanks

Comment: It depends on the screen size. I'm not experiencing this.

Comment: Hmm, so do you think there is no way of controlling this dependant on screen size then? I can see a remedy for the average screen size by adding more margin to the bottom of the div element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just Kai Qing's answer extended with a header:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">...</div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="home">Some home page stuff</div>
        <div id="about">About us</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

css:

```
body, #header, #container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#header, #container {
    position:absolute;
}
#header {
    top:0;
    height: 30%; /* or em or whatever */
}
#container {
    bottom: 0;
    top: 30%; /* when using percentages of course we also could've used height */
}
#home, #about {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

So you should not need any javascript for height magic.

Answer (score 1):

You would set each page section's height to match the user's screen.

I've done many ajax only sites and the general layout I follow is something like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="home">Some home page stuff</div>
    <div id="about">About us</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
body{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#home, #about{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Then I move container about as needed.
It looks like your site is pretty much doing this except that you don't set a height for each area. Understandably since it has that constant header where the remainder of the screen is not a constant percentage. You can use jquery to reset inner element heights on load to get each section to match the right area.

the general concept is

```
$(window).height() - $('header').height() = your viewport height
```

which you then apply to each inner page as needed.